# Poner en edición una celda de DataGridView desde el evento Load de un formulario

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Trabajo con Windows Forms, Visual Studio 2019

Tengo la necesidad de poner en edición una celda del DataGridView desde el evento load del formulario.

He intentado de la siguiente manera

```
private void FrmRecuento_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int index = 0;
        Utilidades.CentrarFrm(this);
        lblEfectivoCaja.Text = Convert.ToString(_efectivoCaja);
        LoadDgvRecuento();
        if (dgvRecuento.Rows.Count > 0 && dgvRecuento.CurrentRow != null)
        {
            dgvRecuento.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
            index = dgvRecuento.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
            dgvRecuento.CurrentCell = dgvRecuento.Rows[index].Cells["colCantidad"];
            dgvRecuento.BeginEdit(true);
        }

    }
```

El problema que tengo es que no queda en estado de edición la celda que indico, no se como tomar el index de la primera fila del DGV.

¿Como puedo solucionarlo?
Saludos!

Comment: pero cual es la celda que quieres poner en edicion ? no hay un CurrentRow si recien acabas de cargar el grid, se supone que el current representa la seleccion del usuario

Comment: @LeandroTuttini Deseo poner en edición una celda que se llama colCantidad, tienes razón no he seleccionado nada, al llamar al formulario carga el grid con datos y debo mostrar seleccionada la primera fila y debe estar en edición la celda cantidad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logre solucionarlo

```
dgvRecuento.EditMode = DataGridViewEditMode.EditOnEnter;
dgvRecuento.CurrentCell = dgvRecuento.Rows[0].Cells["colCantidad"];
dgvRecuento.CurrentCell.Selected = true;
```

Answer (score 1):

Si la idea es poner en edicion la primer fila entonces puede seleccionarla directamente, no necesitas usar el `CurrentRow`

```
private void FrmRecuento_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Utilidades.CentrarFrm(this);
    lblEfectivoCaja.Text = Convert.ToString(_efectivoCaja);

    LoadDgvRecuento();

    if (dgvRecuento.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        dgvRecuento.CurrentCell = dgvRecuento.Rows[0].Cells["colCantidad"];
        dgvRecuento.BeginEdit(true);
    }

}
```

como veras use el `0 cero` indicando la primer row

Ademas el `SelectionMode` con `FullRowSelect` puedes definirlo en diseño, no hace falta que sea desde codigo

Comment: Leandro si selecciona el primer row pero no pone en edición la celda indicada por que no sale el puntero palpitando. Si estuviera en edición solo tendría que digitar para que se muestre los números que ingreso.

Comment: quizas lo que falte es poner el foco en el control grid para que aparezca el cursor de input

Comment: `dgvRecuento.Focus();
                dgvRecuento.CurrentCell = dgvRecuento.Rows[0].Cells["colCantidad"];
                dgvRecuento.BeginEdit(true);`No me ha funcionado poniendo el foco en el DGv

Comment: Derrepente puede ser en otro evento como en el evento del DGV porque una vez que tenga el foco en la primera celda cuando cargue el form al precionar ENTER debo ir de row en row,

Answer (score 0):

Revisando la pregunta varias veces caí en cuenta que el problema es el siguiente.

```
        //borrar esta linea.
        index = dgvRecuento.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
```

si lo que necesitas es señalar el primer `Row` del `DataGridView` haciendo 
`dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells["colCantidad"];` ya valdría.